# resetting the password for some of ZkTeck fingerprint machine

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm new in code it's a first time to write a code in python and other languages
i want to know if there is something wrong with the code and why when i open it as an EXE it takes so long to open.

## resetting the password for some of ZkTeck fingerprint machine

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('ZkTeco Password Reset')
root.config(bg='orange')

def zkteco():
    try:
        time = int(a.get())
        result = 9999 - time
        x = result * result
        label.config(text=(f"Username: 8888\nPassword: {x}"))
    except ValueError:
    print("Inter Valid Number")

Label(root, text="Enter the time on the machine screen!",
            font=('calibri', 30, 'bold'),
            background='orange',
            foreground='white').pack()

a = Entry(root, width=36)
a.pack()

label = Label(root, text="",
        font=('Arial', 15, 'bold'),
        background="black",
        width=18,
        foreground="white")
label.pack(pady=20)

Button(root, text="Calculate",
       background="green",
       width=20,
       foreground="black",
       command=zkteco).pack()
Button(root,
       text='Exit',
       width=20,
       background="green",
       foreground="black",
       command=root.quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me (once I fix the indentation of the `print` statement).  The window comes up immediately.  What operating system?

Comment: windows 11 operating system

Comment: Enter time like this 2:30 or just 2? I entered 2 and it worked .